# Angular ngFor showing two items in a row

Tags: arrays, angular

I'm running into a problem with my code. I'm trying to show a 4 by 8 grid using ngFor command. Provided below is my code:

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let word of Words; let i = index;">
                <div class="row" *ngIf="((i % 2) == 0)"  style="margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" >
                  <div class="col-sm-1 text-center" style="padding: 20px 10px; border: 1px solid black"> {{ i+1 }}</div>
                  <div class="col-sm-5 text-center example-box" *ngIf="word == Words[i]" style="border: 1px solid black" cdkDrag>{{ word.Title }}</div>
                  <div class="col-sm-1 text-center" style="padding: 20px 10px; border: 1px solid black"> {{ i+2 }}</div>
                  <div class="col-sm-5 text-center example-box" *ngIf="word == Words[i+1]" style="border: 1px solid black" cdkDrag>{{ word.Title }}</div>
                </div>

            </ng-container>
          </div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the grid shows the word.Title in the left column, but in the right column it just shows the number ({{ i + 2 }} ) text and now the word.Title content. See image below:
[image]

As you can see the even number column, the content in the new column does not appear.

How do I get the 4 column to appear in my table?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In fourth div you seem to have wrong ngif condition i.e. *ngIf="word == Words[i+1]"

Comment: If your Words array has only one entry, that time `*ngIf="word == Words[i+1]"` will always be set to false thereby not showing it on the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made 3 changes

- On the first sub div, I removed the *ngIf condition
- On the second sub div, I changed word.Title to Words[i]
- On the third sub div, I updated the *ngIf to Words[i+1] !== undefined
- On the fourth sub div, I changed word.Title to Words[i+1]

{{ i+1 }}

{{ Words[i].Title }}

 {{ i+2 }}

{{ Words[i+1].Title }}

Comment: For 4th Sub div, If your words array has only entry, `Words[i+1]` which is `Words[0 +1]` .i.e `Words[1]` in this case will always be undefined hence `Words[i+1].Title`  will throw an error